# Why there are multiple savepoints inside nested transaction?

Tags: sqlalchemy

For testing purpose I'm trying to implement the way to use a single test database for every tests launch in CI. Let's imagine that first launch was started. And in 5 seconds second was started. Tests generate some data. So the data produced in first launch should not affect the second launch. Actually the data should be isolated even between tests of a single launch.

I eager to develop next pipeline:

- create database if not exists
- open outer transaction
- migrate alembic
- (for each test:)
- open nested transaction
- run test
- rollback nested transaction (delete all data generated during the test)
- (end test)
- rollback outer transaction

So for that I developed some code:

```
import asyncio
import logging
import os
from pathlib import Path

import pytest as pytest
from alembic import command
from alembic.config import Config
from sqlalchemy import URL, text, Connection
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import create_async_engine, AsyncSession, AsyncConnection

from src.config import settings

logger = logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def event_loop():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop_policy().new_event_loop()
    yield loop
    loop.close()


async def migrate(conn: AsyncConnection) -> None:
    def upgrade(connection: Connection):
        base_dir = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
        alembic_cfg = Config(os.path.join(base_dir, "alembic.ini"))
        alembic_cfg.attributes["connection"] = connection
        command.upgrade(alembic_cfg, "head")

    await conn.run_sync(upgrade)


async def database_exists(conn: AsyncConnection, datname: str) -> bool:
    stmt = text(f"SELECT 1 FROM pg_database WHERE datname='{datname}'")
    ret = await conn.execute(stmt)

    return ret.scalar() == 1


async def create_database(conn: AsyncConnection, name: str):
    stmt = text(f'CREATE DATABASE "{name}" ENCODING "utf8" TEMPLATE template1')
    await conn.execute(stmt)


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
async def connection():
    url = URL.create(
        drivername=settings.db.drivername,
        host=settings.db.host,
        port=settings.db.port,
        username=settings.db.username,
        password=settings.db.password,
    )

    database = "test_database"
    engine = create_async_engine(url, isolation_level="AUTOCOMMIT", echo=True)

    async with engine.connect() as conn:
        if not database_exists(conn, database):
            await create_database(conn, database)

    await engine.dispose()

    url = url.set(database=database)
    engine = create_async_engine(url)

    async with engine.begin() as connection:
        print("OUTER TRANSACTION OPENED")
        await migrate(connection)
        yield connection
        await connection.rollback()
        print("OUTER TRANSACTION ROLLBACKED")
        await connection.close()

    await engine.dispose()


@pytest.fixture
async def session(connection: AsyncConnection):
    print("OPEN NESTED TRANSACTION")
    savepoint = await connection.begin_nested()
    print("NESTED TRANSACTION OPENED")
    session = AsyncSession(bind=connection)
    yield session
    await session.close()
    print("ROLLBACK NESTED TRANSACTION")
    await savepoint.rollback()
    print("NESTED TRANSACTION ROLLBACKED")
```

And two tests:

```
import logging

from sqlalchemy import select
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession

from src.models import User

logger = logging.getLogger('sqlalchemy.engine')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)


async def test_john(session: AsyncSession):
    print("BEFORE SELECT users")
    users = await session.scalars(select(User))
    print("AFTER SELECT users")
    assert users.all() == []
    john = User(name="John")
    session.add(john)
    print("BEFORE COMMIT")
    await session.commit()
    print("AFTER COMMIT")
    users = await session.scalars(select(User))
    assert users.all() == [john]


async def test_sansa(session: AsyncSession):
    users = await session.scalars(select(User))
    assert users.all() == []
    sansa = User(name="Sansa")
    session.add(sansa)
    await session.commit()
    users = await session.scalars(select(User))
    assert users.all() == [sansa]
```

Launching tests produced logs:

```
DEBUG    asyncio:selector_events.py:54 Using selector: KqueueSelector
DEBUG    asyncio:selector_events.py:54 Using selector: KqueueSelector
2023-11-07 22:34:38,415 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine select pg_catalog.version()
INFO     sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:base.py:1848 select pg_catalog.version()
2023-11-07 22:34:38,415 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] ()
INFO     sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:base.py:1848 [raw sql] ()
2023-11-07 22:34:38,419 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine select current_schema()
INFO     sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:base.py:1848 select current_schema()
2023-11-07 22:34:38,419 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] ()
INFO     sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:base.py:1848 [raw sql] ()
2023-11-07 22:34:38,423 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine show standard_conforming_strings
INFO     sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:base.py:1848 show standard_conforming_strings
2023-11-07 22:34:38,423 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] ()
INFO     sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:base.py:1848 [raw sql] ()
2023-11-07 22:34:38,477 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine select pg_catalog.version()
INFO     sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:base.py:1848 select pg_catalog.version()
2023-11-07 22:34:38,478 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] ()
INFO     sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:base.py:1848 [raw sql] ()
2023-11-07 22:34:38,481 DEBUG sqlalchemy.engine.Engine Col ('version',)
DEBUG    sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:cursor.py:1439 Col ('version',)
2023-11-07 22:34:38,481 DEBUG sqlalchemy.engine.Engine Row ('PostgreSQL 14.0 (Debian 14.0-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit',)
DEBUG    sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:cursor.py:1470 Row ('PostgreSQL 14.0 (Debian 14.0-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit',)
2023-11-07 22:34:38,481 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine select current_schema()
INFO     sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:base.py:1848 select current_schema()
2023-11-07 22:34:38,481 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] ()
INFO     sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:base.py:1848 [raw sql] ()
2023-11-07 22:34:38,483 DEBUG sqlalchemy.engine.Engine Col ('current_schema',)
DEBUG    sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:cursor.py:1439 Col ('current_schema',)
2023-11-07 22:34:38,483 DEBUG sqlalchemy.engine.Engine Row ('public',)
DEBUG    sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:cursor.py:1470 Row ('public',)
2023-11-07 22:34:38,485 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine show standard_conforming_strings
INFO     sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:base.py:1848 show standard_conforming_strings
2023-11-07 22:34:38,485 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] ()
INFO     sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:base.py:1848 [raw sql] ()
2023-11-07 22:34:38,486 DEBUG sqlalchemy.engine.Engine Col ('standard_conforming_strings',)
DEBUG    sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:cursor.py:1439 Col ('standard_conforming_strings',)
2023-11-07 22:34:38,486 DEBUG sqlalchemy.engine.Engine Row ('on',)
DEBUG    sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:cursor.py:1470 Row ('on',)
2023-11-07 22:34:38,487 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
INFO     sqlalchemy.engine.Engine:base.py:2689 BEGIN (implicit)
OUTER TRANSACTION OPENED
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl PostgresqlImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume transactional DDL.
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] SELECT pg_catalog.pg_class.relname 
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace ON pg_catalog.pg_namespace.oid = pg_catalog.pg_class.relnamespace 
WHERE pg_catalog.pg_class.relname = $1::VARCHAR AND pg_catalog.pg_class.relkind = ANY (ARRAY[$2::VARCHAR, $3::VARCHAR, $4::VARCHAR, $5::VARCHAR, $6::VARCHAR]) AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(pg_catalog.pg_class.oid) AND pg_catalog.pg_namespace.nspname != $7::VARCHAR
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] [generated in 0.00014s] ('alembic_version', 'r', 'p', 'f', 'v', 'm', 'pg_catalog')
DEBUG [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] Col ('relname',)
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] SELECT pg_catalog.pg_class.relname 
FROM pg_catalog.pg_class JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace ON pg_catalog.pg_namespace.oid = pg_catalog.pg_class.relnamespace 
WHERE pg_catalog.pg_class.relname = $1::VARCHAR AND pg_catalog.pg_class.relkind = ANY (ARRAY[$2::VARCHAR, $3::VARCHAR, $4::VARCHAR, $5::VARCHAR, $6::VARCHAR]) AND pg_catalog.pg_table_is_visible(pg_catalog.pg_class.oid) AND pg_catalog.pg_namespace.nspname != $7::VARCHAR
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] [cached since 0.004169s ago] ('alembic_version', 'r', 'p', 'f', 'v', 'm', 'pg_catalog')
DEBUG [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] Col ('relname',)
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] 
CREATE TABLE alembic_version (
        version_num VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL, 
        CONSTRAINT alembic_version_pkc PRIMARY KEY (version_num)
)


INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] [no key 0.00006s] ()
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade  -> 7ef00e32f734, empty message
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] 
CREATE TABLE users (
        id SERIAL NOT NULL, 
        name VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
)


INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] [no key 0.00006s] ()
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] INSERT INTO alembic_version (version_num) VALUES ('7ef00e32f734') RETURNING alembic_version.version_num
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] [generated in 0.00010s] ()
DEBUG [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] Col ('version_num',)
DEBUG [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] Row ('7ef00e32f734',)
OPEN NESTED TRANSACTION
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] SAVEPOINT sa_savepoint_1
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] [no key 0.00007s] ()
NESTED TRANSACTION OPENED
BEFORE SELECT users
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] SAVEPOINT sa_savepoint_2
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] [no key 0.00010s] ()
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] SELECT users.id, users.name 
FROM users
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] [generated in 0.00009s] ()
DEBUG [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] Col ('id', 'name')
AFTER SELECT users
BEFORE COMMIT
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ($1::VARCHAR) RETURNING users.id
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] [generated in 0.00010s] ('John',)
DEBUG [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] Col ('id',)
DEBUG [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] Row (1,)
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] RELEASE SAVEPOINT sa_savepoint_2
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] [no key 0.00007s] ()
AFTER COMMIT
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] SAVEPOINT sa_savepoint_3
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] [no key 0.00009s] ()
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] SELECT users.id, users.name 
FROM users
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] [cached since 0.008259s ago] ()
DEBUG [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] Col ('id', 'name')
DEBUG [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] Row (1, 'John')
PASSEDINFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT sa_savepoint_3
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] [no key 0.00008s] ()
ROLLBACK NESTED TRANSACTION
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT sa_savepoint_1
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] [no key 0.00008s] ()
NESTED TRANSACTION ROLLBACKED

tests/test_ex.py::test_sansa OPEN NESTED TRANSACTION
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] SAVEPOINT sa_savepoint_4
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] [no key 0.00008s] ()
NESTED TRANSACTION OPENED
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] SAVEPOINT sa_savepoint_5
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] [no key 0.00008s] ()
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] SELECT users.id, users.name 
FROM users
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] [cached since 0.01876s ago] ()
DEBUG [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] Col ('id', 'name')
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] INSERT INTO users (name) VALUES ($1::VARCHAR) RETURNING users.id
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] [cached since 0.01751s ago] ('Sansa',)
DEBUG [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] Col ('id',)
DEBUG [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] Row (2,)
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] RELEASE SAVEPOINT sa_savepoint_5
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] [no key 0.00007s] ()
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] SAVEPOINT sa_savepoint_6
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] [no key 0.00009s] ()
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] SELECT users.id, users.name 
FROM users
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] [cached since 0.02466s ago] ()
DEBUG [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] Col ('id', 'name')
DEBUG [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] Row (2, 'Sansa')
PASSEDINFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT sa_savepoint_6
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] [no key 0.00008s] ()
ROLLBACK NESTED TRANSACTION
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT sa_savepoint_4
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] [no key 0.00007s] ()
NESTED TRANSACTION ROLLBACKED
INFO  [sqlalchemy.engine.Engine] ROLLBACK
OUTER TRANSACTION ROLLBACKED
```

As you can see after `savepoint = await connection.begin_nested()` savepoint `sa_savepoint_1` being create. This is expected. But also after that another savepoint `sa_savepoint_2` being created and it lasts until `commit`. And after `commit` another savepoing being created.

Why there are multiple savepoints instead of single one?